# Configure server port when running jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jar, server-configuration

I currently working on an Spring Boot application written in Java 8 using Gradle. 
What I am looking for is to pass as an argument the server port when running the Jar from the command line.

For example:

- `java -jar myApplication.jar --port=8888`: This runs my Spring boot application using port `8888`
- `java -jar myApplication.jar`: Since no port number is passed as argument, the spring boot application should run on a default port number (let's say `8080`)

Can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

From [Spring boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-change-the-http-port), the command line is :

```
java -Dserver.port=8888 -jar myApplication.jar
```

You can also use Spring boot configuration file as described in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).

Answer (score 9):

**Caution** Always pass the `-D<key>=<value>` JVM parameters **before** the `-jar` arguments otherwise it wouldn't accept your parameters and then it will run with default values. e.g:

Correct java command to execute the jar on a particular port is:

```
java -Dserver.port=8888 -jar target/my-application-jar-path.jar
```

The above command will run the JVM on the port **8888** but the below command

```
java -jar target/my-application-jar-path.jar -Dserver.port=8888
```

Will run on the port **8080**, it will **ignore the JVM parameters after -jar**

Best practice in spring-boot application is to set the `server.port` into the `application.properties` file as:

```
server.port=9090
```

Or on the particular `application-<ENV>.properties` file with specific **ENVIROMENT**.

Answer (score 3):

##### For SpringBoot use:

```sh
 java -jar app.jar --server.port=9000
```

(taken from [2.1. Accessing Command Line Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config) in the Spring documents)